# Why am I getting the operationalerror near 'VARCHAR' during SQL call in Python?

Tags: python, sql, database

I'm receiving 'OperationalError: near "VARCHAR": syntax error' when I call this function, what am I doing wrong?

```
def database_create_user(table_name, user_ID, username, password, creator_exp):
    users_db_curs.execute("INSERT INTO `" + table_name + "` (uID VARCHAR(20), username VARCHAR(20), password VARCHAR(30), creator_exp VARCHAR(20)) VALUES ('" + user_ID + "', '" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + creator_exp + "')")
    users_db_connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the table has already been created, you do not need to re-specify the column types in each INSERT query.  You could just do:

```
users_db_curs.execute("INSERT INTO `" + table_name + "` (user_ID, username , password , creator_exp ) VALUES ('" + user_ID + "', '" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + creator_exp + "')")
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't specify the data types in the INSERT statement. I have removed the data types that appeared in the INSERT statement. Here is the corrected version.

The code is wrapped here into multiple lines for clarity and readability.

```
def database_create_user(table_name, user_ID, username, password, creator_exp):
users_db_curs.execute("INSERT INTO `" + table_name + "` (uID, username, 
password, creator_exp) VALUES ('" + user_ID + "', '" + username + "', 
'" + password + "', '" + creator_exp + "')")
users_db_connection.commit()
```